# Hashing password not working after using await

Tags: node.js, api, rest, bcrypt

I am trying to hash a password after updating it but I dont understand why it is just working after the await line. In the res.json I get the hashed password, but just there.
I am new to this so I appreciate any help or advice.

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
let { mail, password } = req.body;

bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function (err, salt) {
if (err) return next(err);

bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  password = hash;
});
});

const newUser = { mail, password };
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, newUser);
res.json({ mensaje: `Updated Password ${password}` });
});
```

Comment: You need to look into async/await and callbacks. You're mixing both here and the callbacks to calling crypt.genSalt and bcrypt.hash don't fire in sequential order. You should look at moving your bcrypt implementation to promises and use async/await or move your newUser lines into the bcrypt.hash callback

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me I moved the newUser lines inside the hash function and made it async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you should look into async/await and callbacks more to understand the call order. As it's not running in the sequential fashion you think it is. But you can try the following.

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  let { mail, password } = req.body;
  try{
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    const newUser = { mail, password };
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, newUser);
    res.json({ mensaje: `Updated Password ${password}` });
  } catch(error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});
```